# Codeigniter csrf token with ajax request (500 internal server error)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, csrf-protection

I'm having a hard time trying to make an ajax request through my CI form having the csrf token enabled. I've been doing a long research and I came up with the same solution is posted in every issue related with this one which is adding the token val to the serialized data in the ajax request. I did this in my ajaxSetup, I get the token but still experiencing the same issue.. Here is my code.

```
//AJAX Setup

$.ajaxSetup({

    data:{

        csrf_test_name: $("input[name='csrf_test_name']").val()
    }

 });  

//Function ajax login

$("form#login").on("submit", function(e){

    var $this = $(this);
    var mensaje = $("div.msglogin");

    $.ajax({

        type: "POST",
        url: $this.attr("action"),
        data: $this.serialize(),
        beforeSend: function() {
            mensaje.html('<p><img src="public/frontend/img/miniloader.gif"><span><small> Iniciando..</small></span></p>');
        }
    })

    .done (function(data){
        console.log($this.serialize());
            if(data == "redirect"){
                window.location.replace($("input#baselogin").val());
            }else{
                mensaje.html(data);
            }
    })

    e.preventDefault();

});
```

This is what I get when I console.log $this.serialize() which means the token is being send

```
csrf_test_name=4a4d6eb47fc8f0c8e932b3b56a4eb9c5&usuario=dan&password=meaannn
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: csrf token in codeigniter (from what I've read) is notorious for not working, so it's much easier not to use it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the CSRF token to your `data` option before posting:

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: $this.attr("action"),
    data: {'<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>':'<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash(); ?>',/*....your data....*/},
    beforeSend: function() {
        mensaje.html('<p><img src="public/frontend/img/miniloader.gif"><span><small> Iniciando..</small></span></p>');
    }
})
```

The CSRF token needs to be sent with each request so it should be specified by the data. The `echo` statement does this. You can add this separately and serialize, but I've shown what you are missing.